# Only getting a single character in return from function instead of a character array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I've tried to write a program to reverse a string without using the `strrev()` function.

The problem I am getting is that when I ran the program, I only got 'd' as an output instead of the whole reversed string 'dlroW olleH'
Please help me to get the whole string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<String.h>

char reverse(char s[])
{
    int c, i, j;

    for(i = 0,j = strlen(s) - 1; I < j; i++, j--)
    {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }

    return *s;
}
void main()
{
    char str[12] = "Hello World";
    char result = reverse(str);
    printf("%c", result);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: You get only one char because you only return onw char. You're mixing up string and char.

Comment: Well, your function explicitly returns one `char`acter: `char reverse(char s[])`, and you know it because you assign its result to the variable of type `char`: `char result = reverse(str)` and use the `%c` format specifier meant for single `char`acters.

Answer (score 3):

**You have several problems in the program:**

1. There's no such header file `String.h`, but `string.h`.
2. Because you are interested to return the entire string, not a single char. Change the return type of the `reverse()` function with `char*` from `char`, and remove the dereference operator from its return statement, i.e. `return s;`.
3. Replace this after the edits:

   ```
   char result = reverse(str);
   printf("%c", result);
   ```

   with:

   ```
   char *result = reverse(str);
   printf("%s", result);
   ```

---

The entire program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // Fixed the possible typo

// Prototype fixed
char* reverse(char s[]) {
  int c, i, j;

  for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    c = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = c;
  }

  return s; // Proper return statement
}

// main() must return an integer to the OS
int main(void) {
  char str[12] = "Hello World";
  char* result = reverse(str);

  printf("%s\n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6ch6ec).

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. I am sorry that I have made a silly mistake by declaring #include<String.h>. I didn't notice that because the compiler didn't give me any error.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char s[])    // return a char* and not a char
{
  int c, i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
  {
    c = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = c;
  }

  return s;    // return a char* and not a char. return *s would return the 1st char only
}

void main()
{
  char str[12] = "Hello World";
  char* result = reverse(str);    // result must be a char* and not a single char
  printf("%s", result);           // use %s for char*
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried the same code but that gave me an error because of the string,h declaration. Now I can die peacefully.